# printing problems from computer to printer

Tags: windows-7, printing

I have a Windows 7 computer desk top wireless connected to a HP Photo smart printer. This printer works ok. Computers are routinely refused to print. Can I tell what might be wrong and how to fix it. help me!!!!plesae

Comment: We are going to need a lot more detail. Are there other (any?) computers that can print to this printer? Has it ever worked? What type of printer is it? Can you print from the computer if it is hardwired in?

Comment: printer can not run on my laptop but on the other laptop can My printer type TX21

Comment: first check the connectivity using ping <printer ip> if its OK then check whether if others are able to take a printout if you are using a network printer else go to the printer check whether any other job running using interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a work around you could enable printer sharing in Windows HomeGroup, and then go to Network in the left-hand pane in Windows Explorer (the thing that shows files). Then click on your laptop and then click on the printer. Then your desktop would be printing through your laptop. 
Also you could try restarting your computer and printer, as well as your wireless router, then attempt to set up the printer manually via Printers & Devices. Just type Printers in the search bar in the start menu and that (or similar) should pop up.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!